# 2 floating point numbers does a calculation

Tags: android, floating-point

I am trying to write a very simple Android app. 
It takes in 2 floating point numbers, does a calculation,

When I run my app, it crashes.

However, if I enter integers instead of floating point numbers, my 
program doesn't crash and does the correct calculation.

How to solve this problem? thx a lot

```
private Button.OnClickListener btnTranListener =new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){
        int amount=Integer.parseInt(editfc.getText().toString());
        double $=1.24*(double)amount;
        $ = (double) (((int)($ * 1000)) / 1000.0);
        outelc124.setText("ELC(1.24)= " + $ + " /pc");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Integer.parseInt()` with `Double.parseDouble()` and you will be able to handle numbers with decimals or integers.

You can also catch `NumberformatException` to keep it from crashing if they enter other bogus input.